# TeX daemon for Windows

Tags: preamble, windows

A simple question (in theory): is there any (La)TeX distribution for Windows that is capable of running as a daemon? I am not aware that either MiKTeX or TeX Live are capable as running as daemons on Windows, but are there any other solutions? Failing this, if I wanted to hack an existing TeX distribution to run as a daemon, what would be the best approach?

A few features that the daemon should have, ideally:

- One-time loading.
- Load the preamble separately, so multiple documents can be generated without reloading the preamble.
- Run as a Windows Service. (optional)
- Callable as a library/API. (optional)
- Input TeX and output DVI/PNG via standard I/O or pipes. (optional)

Any information or suggestions on the subject would be much appreciated.

**Edit 1:** Specifically, I am also rather curious how the [*preview-latex*](http://www.gnu.org/software/auctex/preview-latex.html) package for EMACS works. This seems to have a very similar usage in mind to what I intend.

**Edit 2:** I've just recalled that the [Instant Preview](http://wiki.lyx.org/LyX/InstantPreview) feature of LyX also closely represents what I want to achieve. Additionally, this seems to work on Windows. An explanation/overview of this system and the daemon it uses would be very helpful.

Answer (score 6):

There is William Blum's LaTeXDaemon:

http://william.famille-blum.org/software/latexdaemon/index.html

It's on Google code as well, but I am only allowed one hyperlink.

It will generate a format for the preamble and re-compile every time the document is saved.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I've actually looked at this before and it doesn't seem to be a true TeX daemon. It's mainly a file system watcher from what I can tell. It is also mysterious how it "precompiles" the preamble using only a standard MiKTeX distribution.

Comment: In response to your other answer: Cheers, that explains half the story. However, doesn't this LaTeXDaemon still have to relaunch the LaTeX program on each run? Where is the preamble preserved in that case?

Answer (score 6):

[MathTran](http://www.mathtran.org) runs TeX as a daemon.  For macros it runs a secure variant of plain TeX, but with some LaTeX additions, such as `\frac`.  Several years ago it could typeset a single formula in about 10 milliseconds (and so too cheap to be worth caching).

There's an [experimental online editor](http://www.mathtran.org/editor/), which gives instant preview (if you have a good internet connection).

To learn more about the technology behind MathTran go to [its wiki](http://www.mathtran.org/wiki/).

*Disclaimer*: I'm the developer of MathTran.

Comment: Looks like a pretty nice project there. Judging by the username, it seems you're also a main developer on the [TeX Daemon](http://sourceforge.net/projects/texd/) project on SF.net, though this and the (forked?) PyTeX project look to be Linux only - correct me if I'm wrong. What does MathTran use internally? I suppose there's no chance of open-sourcing it? :)

Comment: Yes, I'm behind the TeX daemon also.  The MathTran site is open-source, but not as easy to get hold of and install as I would like.  For technical reasons, the TeX daemon requires Unix style sockets (so that it can make a select()).

Comment: I see... In that case, do you have any idea what Instant Preview does (for LyX), especially when running on Windows? It seems you're responsible for this project to, judging by a paper written in 2001.

Answer (score 3):

The "mysterious precompilation" by LaTeXDeamon is done by creating a custom format using [mylatex](http://ctan.org/pkg/mylatex).

Comment: LaTeXDaemon must compile your document again loading of packages and definitions from the preamble are dumped to a format file and is therefore much quicker than if you compile in the tradidtional way. Try making a document (test.tex) that loads TikZ or other huge packages and then create a custom format with mylatex: 

(one line):
pdftex -ini -fmt=mytest -jobname=mytest -progname=pdflatex \&pdflatex mylatex.ltx test.tex 

this will generate mytest.fmt and you can now compile the document with 

pdftex -fmt=mytest.fmt test.tex

Comment: Thanks Martin, that makes things pretty clear to me now. This sort of confirms my view though, that LaTeXDaemon is not a *true* daemon in that stays running indefinitely and can serve multiple users.

Answer (score 3):

The [BaKoMa TeX system](http://www.bakoma-tex.com/) has a dynamical preview feature that you might find interesting as well.